# c++winrt Entry Point Not Found

Tags: c++-winrt

Debug Any32 and Debug Any64 Throws below exception :

```
Exception thrown at 0x77BF6290 (ntdll.dll) in UserInterface.exe: 0xC0000139: Entry Point Not Found.
```

Output Log :

```
'UserInterface.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'UserInterface.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.29231.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\concrt140d_app.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'UserInterface.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.29231.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\vcruntime140d_app.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'UserInterface.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\UserInterface\bin\Debug32\AppX\ucrtbased.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'UserInterface.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.29231.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\msvcp140d_atomic_wait_app.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'UserInterface.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.29231.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\msvcp140_1d_app.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Exception thrown at 0x77BF6290 (ntdll.dll) in UserInterface.exe: 0xC0000139: Entry Point Not Found.
```

Everything works fine in Release. What can be the reason?

Command outcome : dumpbin /dependents UserInterface.exe

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.29.30038.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file UserInterface.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

  Image has the following dependencies:

    api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-winrt-error-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll
    MSVCP140D_APP.dll
    KERNEL32.dll
    USER32.dll
    ADVAPI32.dll
    ole32.dll
    SHELL32.dll
    OLEAUT32.dll
    SHLWAPI.dll
    VERSION.dll
    CONCRT140D_APP.dll
    WS2_32.dll
    VCRUNTIME140D_APP.dll
    ucrtbased.dll
    api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
    api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll
    MSVCP140D_ATOMIC_WAIT_APP.dll
    api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-1.dll
    api-ms-win-core-processtopology-obsolete-l1-1-0.dll
    MSVCP140_1D_APP.dll
    api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll

  Summary

      1AB000 .data
        4000 .msvcjmc
      53C000 .rdata
      109000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
     234E000 .text
        1000 .tls
```

Comment: Is that a UWP app? And have you tried on different devices to see if the same behavior happens?

Comment: Yes, it's UWP App. We tried on several PCs. All of us facing this issue for this particular app and only in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not related to C++/WinRT specifically, but to link dependencies.  Debug builds often have different link dependencies from Release builds.  The CRT DLLs listed in the output spew offer an example of this.  Try running this from a Visual Studio command prompt to see what specific dependencies are not being resolved:

> dumpbin /dependents UserInterface.exe

Comment: This command lists the dependencies, not showing if anything is missing. Please see the edit.